# Accessing files from secondary storage in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

How to access, read and write files from mounted secondary storage volumes connected via OTG to an android phone in flutter? Mount point is shown as /mnt/media_rw/. The packages such as path_provider, external_path are unable access mounted volumes. Target device is Android 13.

i observed that "path_provider" can give access to app storage only (data directory) and with "external_path" package i could see internal storage only.

---

```
import 'package:external_path/external_path.dart';

List<String> path = await ExternalPath.getExternalStorageDirectories();
print('path of all ext. devices: {$path}');
```

---

the result of print was: /storage/emulated/0.

Comment: I have the same issue.

However, if I manually input the path with the storage ID like mnt/media_rw/07-AM50, I can access the storage.

I want to automatically retrieve the storage ID without any manual intervention.